# Robotium How to test with background Services like conversion?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robotium

I am using Robotium Recorder to test my app. My problem is in my app i am doing audio  conversions in background which take some time based on how much time user is recording.

Example

If i am running a test which records for 10mins (Converts in background) each time like this 10 times it records so  **when my last recording that is 10th recording finishes robotium exits and kill the app.**

****Problem:- For last recording my file still need to convert its converting in background (Service) but app is killed so converting failed. I cannot use solo.sleep(int) because i dont know how much time it will take to convert ****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution

In `testRun()` function call `isServiceRunning()` function.

```
public void testRun() {
    .
    .
    if(isSurviceRunning()) {
        solo.sleep(time);
    }
}
```

This method check for background services of your app and return boolean.

```
public boolean isServiceRunning() {      
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if ("com.pakage.name.yourcls.your_service_name".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        Log.d("Running Service is->", "" + service.service.getClassName());
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.d("false", "" + service.service.getClassName());
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `solo.waitForCondition()`

```
final int TIMEOUT = 5000;
Assert.assertTrue(solo.waitForCondition(new Condition() {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied() {
        // return true if the file has been converted.
    }
}, TIMEOUT));
```