# Robotium Android How to stop the app being killed after test completes.?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

Normally when we run the test app is killed after test completes. But in my case i am running couple of background services (cloud sync ) so i dont want to kill the app until service finishes its tasks.

What i tried is

In teardown i removed the methods

solo.finishOpenedActivities(); and 
super.tearDown();

```
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    //super.tearDown();
}
```

but it still kills the app.

**Solutions needed.**

1-> Dont kill the app after test completes.

**Or**

2 -> Kill the app after background service finishes its task.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want one test to run as long as the service lives ? This would make more sense I guess.

Comment: The best solution is solo.waitForCondition(). Your condition's isSatisfied method must return true only when your service is finished. See the answer to your earlier question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25857889/1664038

Answer (score 0):

If you want one test to live as long as your background service still lives, maybe with a timeout to get sure the test always finishes, then you should :

- bind to your service inside the test
- listen to the service completion, this means you have to be able to notfied of the service's lifecycle via the binder
- unbind from it when you receive an event from the service
- you can use CountDownLatch to get sure the service finishes properly in your test.

Comment: Thank you i will definately try that. Can you please tell me how to stop the app being killed after test completes. I mean i dont want to kill the app after test is finished this will solve all my problems.

Comment: I don't know how to do that with Robotium and I don't think it's a good practice. The best advice I could give you is in my answer.